# Print out multiple sheets in one pdf based on column value

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, pdf

I have the following workbook in excel and would like to print out a multipage pdf.file consisting the sheet "Oversigt" and then all sheets marked with an x in column D. The sheet name is in column B.

[image: screenshot from excel]

Found this code:

```
Sub PrintOut()
    Dim ary
    Dim a As Variant, fp As String
    ary = Array("Oversigt", "211A", "211B")

    fp = ActiveWorkbook.Path

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ary).Select
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF
End Sub
```

But I need to populate the array based on column B and D and also I would like to be asked where to save my pdf file.

Comment: You can use `GetSaveAsFileName`

Comment: Can you help me with the exact code?